# When I Used [UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:] and - popToRootViewControllerAnimated:, the viewController not dealloc

Tags: ios, release, dealloc

When I Used [UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:] and - popToRootViewControllerAnimated:, for example:

```
- (void)backViewControllerAnimation:(BOOL)animation {
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }

    [OLTabBarController.defaultTabBar.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

the viewController is not dealloc, but if I delete [UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:0], like this:

```
- (void)backViewControllerAnimation:(BOOL)animation {
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

the viewController can dealloc, I want known what happend, I need - setSelectedIndex: method, how can I make viewController perform - dealloc method?

Comment: when you present or entry point of your story board at their you can add your tab controller in navigation controller?

Comment: That's too much work, I need a solution that can fix the problem quickly, because there are not so many man-hour.